# How to find potential difference at A

Tags: circuit-analysis

As shown below the schematic diagram is given.Point B is grounded.

[image]

I did take the potential at A is 2V since it is on the same node where the  2V batteries are located , am I correct? . I want to verify the accuracy of my  answer !. What is your opinion?

Comment: Remember that ground is an arbitrary definition. What would the circuit look like if the negative ends of the voltage sources were connected to GND instead of B? What voltages would you get for A and B then?

Comment: @NickJohnson do you mean the +ve ends?

Comment: @Chu No, the negative ends. Another way to look at it is that the question is asking you what the voltage across the middle resistor is; ignore the GND symbol and calculate that.

Comment: This circuit is **easily** solved using superposition and utilizing the symmetry. And it is not `2V` there, sorry.

Comment: @NickJohnson, I'm ok with ignoring the ground connection, but I don't see how the -ve ends can be joined without reconfiguring the circuit.

Comment: Mind how you formulate your question: A "potential difference at A" is meaningless, because a potential *difference* is by definition *between two points*.

Comment: Of course the -ve ends of the batteries can be joined. You should try and prove that the answer is 1.333 volts (quick brain calc)

Comment: @Chu Wouter's answer describes what I had in mind rather more completely than I did.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to take each one of the branches with batteries and substitute them with their Norton equivalent, i.e. a \$5\Omega\$ resistor in parallel with a \$ \dfrac{2V}{5\Omega}=0.4A\$ current source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f65LKn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then you get three paralleled \$5\Omega\$ resistors driven by two paralleled \$0.4A\$ current sources. This means a total \$0.8A\$ flowing into an equivalent \$\dfrac{5\Omega}{3}\$ resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZiUEo.png)</sup>

By Ohms'law you get:

\$ V_{AB} = \dfrac{5\Omega}{3} \times 0.8A = \dfrac{4}{3}V \approx 1.33V \$

**EDIT**

(Since it seems you have not grasped the concept of circuit ground).

A voltage is an electrical quantity always measured **between two points** in a circuit. Since it is cumbersome to draw schematics full of arrows (or +- symbols) specifying where are all the voltages you need, it is customary to take a common reference point (node, to be precise) for all voltages: that point (that node) is called *circuit ground*. Then you specify only *node voltages*, i.e. voltages between a node and the ground node. That is, for each node *k*, \$V_k = V_{kG} \$ where G indicates ground. *This is a definition!*

So, by marking a node (B in your case) with the ground symbol you are saying that any other node voltage is measured/specified with respect to that node (B). This allows specifying node voltages with only one subscript. Moreover this doesn't lead to a loss of generality, because it can be easily shown that a voltage \$V_{XY}\$ between ***any*** two points X and Y in the circuit can be written as a difference between two node voltages, i.e. \$V_{XY} = V_X - V_Y\$ (if either X or Y is ground, the corresponding node voltage is of course 0).

Comment: Then what is the potential at A?

Comment: Since point B is labeled as ground in the schematic, i.e. B is the reference point for all node voltages, then Va=Vab, by the very definition of circuit ground.

Comment: But how to find potential at A?

Comment: I just told you! The potential at A ***is the same thing*** as the voltage (difference of potential) between A and B! That's because B has been chosen as circuit ground.

Comment: But accoarding to what I have leant potential difference(voltage)is same within a particular node

Comment: You have two nodes here, A and B. B has been chosen as circuit ground, that means that it is taken as reference for all other node voltages. Please, reread my answer. What you call the potential of node A is simply the voltage between node A and ground, which in this case is node B.

Comment: Then you are saying the P.D at A is zero?

Comment: Have you reread my answer? Va=Vab=1.33V. It is Vb which is zero, because it is the potential of B referenced to B itself.

Comment: Okay I read it,let me know , the way you are identifying elements which are in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by stepwise reduction.

1) The left side of the two batteries is connected, hence the right sidse of the batteries have the same potentional. Connect those two point with a wire.

2) Now you have two same-voltage batteries in parallel. Remove one.

3) Now you have two 5 Ohm resistors in parallel. Replace them by a single suitable resistor.

4) Now you have a simple circuit with one battery and two resistors in series. Calculate the current and use it to determine the voltage at the junction of the two resistors. Or alternatively, regard the two resistors as a voltage divider and use that to calculate the voltage at the junction.

Optional step: The fact that the batteries do not have one side grounded might make you a little nervous. But two elements in series can always be swapped without influencing the rest of the circuit, so you could swap both battteries with their series resistors. (But do note that this will influence the voltage at the junction of the battery and its series resistor!)

Comment: Is it possible to do this way, I mean it is like sort of cheating!

Comment: And how could you get step 1 and step 2

Comment: 1: a wire between two points that have the same potential can be added or removed without influence on a circuit, because it will carry no current. 2: two same-voltage batteries in parallel are equivalent to one such battery. (Same holds for two current sources in series.)

Comment: In a lot of situations you can choose between the brute-force approach and cheating. Knowing when (and how!) to cheat is one of the things I try to learn my students. (The brute-force approach is another thing to learn, but it is not my specialty.)

Comment: Btw , how can you say potential are same in negative terminals of two batteries ?

Comment: The left terminals are connected together and hence at the same potential. A battery causes a fixed potential difference across its terminals, so the potentials ate the right terminals are the same too. (Assuming the abtteries are ideal and the same.)

Comment: But they don't share an extra ordinary node, as I know if two elements to be parallel they should share same extraordinary node, I am confused here

Comment: I have no idea what an "extra ordinary" node is.

Comment: Do you know node?

Comment: Are you serious? And when I say 'I have no idea what an "extra ordinary" node is.' the double quotes indicate that the "extra ordinary" part is what I don't understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23950/discussion-between-on-the-way-to-success-and-wouter-van-ooijen).

Comment: @  Wouter van Ooijen: Sorry Mr.   Ooijen, actually I didn't see that you have double quoted only extraordinary. So as I know extraordinary node are which have more than two elements

Answer (score 0):

Your outright guess that node A is 2V with respect to node B is not correct.

There are resistors in series with the two batteries that must be taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

Ground is just a reference point.  Just move the ground to point A and calculate the voltage at B.  The relationship between A and B will always be the same, regardless of where you put ground.